# How to get a pytest fixture interactively?

Tags: python, pytest

How to import or otherwise bind a `pytest` fixture for interactive use, without using breakpoints?

For example, I want to explore some behaviours of the [`tmpdir_factory`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) fixture in the REPL.

```
from pytest import tmpdir_factory  # note: this doesn't actually work

# setup / context has already been entered
tmpdir_factory.ensure('exists.txt', file=True)  # I can use the fixture
del tmpdir_factory  # teardown will eventually be called
```

In the case of `tmpdir` I already know it's just a `py.path.local` instance, but I'm interested in the general question for user defined fixtures too.

---

*edit:* Another acceptable interface:

```
from magical_module import inject_fixture
tmpdir_factory = inject_fixture('tmpdir_factory')
```

---

*edit:* an MCVE to show whether context has exited or not:

```
# conftest.py
from datetime import datetime
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    obj = {'setup': datetime.now()}
    yield (obj, f'yielded @ {datetime.now()!r}')
    obj['teardown'] = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some fixtures are available session-wide, *no fixture gets a value until a test is run*. The simplest way to play with fixtures is to set a breakpoint in a test function... but we can sorta bypass this with some hackery:

```
# magical_module.py
import pytest

_fixture_name = None
_fixture_value = None

def test_stuff(request):
    global _fixture_value
    fixturedef = request._get_active_fixturedef(_fixture_name)
    fixturedef._finalizer = []  # disable fixture teardown
    _fixture_value = fixturedef.cached_result[0]

def inject_fixture(fixturename):
    global _fixture_name
    _fixture_name = fixturename
    pytest.main(['-qq', __file__])
    return _fixture_value
```

Then you can access them from the REPL

```
$ python
Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 08:43:29) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20170519] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from magical_module import inject_fixture
>>> tmpdir_factory = inject_fixture('tmpdir_factory')
.
>>> tmpdir_factory
<_pytest.tmpdir.TempdirFactory object at 0x7fbf22df46a0>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Call **`IPython.embed()`** to drop into IPython's REPL](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#embedding-ipython), and use the [`request` fixture's](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest) [`getfixturevalue()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html#_pytest.fixtures.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue) method to access arbitrary fixture values

```
def test_stuff(request):
    from IPython import embed
    embed()
```

Note: **pytest must be run with the `-s` flag** to [disable capturing of stdout/stderr](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html)

```
$ pytest -s
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.2.1, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/they4kman/.virtualenvs/tmp-26171665bd77f5/src, inifile:
collected 1 item                                                                

test_stuff.py Python 3.6.2 (default, Jul 20 2017, 08:43:29) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: request.getfixturevalue('tmpdir_factory')
Out[1]: <_pytest.tmpdir.TempdirFactory at 0x7f71a7d501d0>
```

[IPython must be installed](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html), of course ;)